# CasperJS/PhatomJS running shell commands

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

For the last few days I have been struggling with running shell commands from CasperJS/PhantomJS.

I am running simple unix sed on a file in node, which runs just fine:

```
var sys = require('sys')

var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;

// executes `sed`
child = exec("sed -i -e '1,1000d' file.name", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
sys.print('stdout: ' + stdout);
sys.print('stderr: ' + stderr);
if (error !== null) {
console.log('exec error: ' + error);
}
});
```

But whenever I run same with CasperJS, it just runs forever, not executing the shell command. Maybe someone could shed some light on this.

I did actually make it work through spawn and execFile functions from PhatomJS, but the issue is that it does not work with large files over 300MB.

Comment: Do you want to launch casperJS child processes with node?

Comment: Nope. I want to execute: "sed -i -e '1,1000d' file.name" in CasperJS successfully.

Comment: See [Git](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/f52044cd3106266aa8efc1fae05e8c923315a5e5/examples/child_process-examples.js) : `"the following methods are not yet implemented : exec, fork".`

Comment: I do know that. But there is spawn and execFile implemented, which can be generally used to execute shell commands, but I could not make them work for large files.

Comment: One solution I have managed to determine is to create separate node.js script, which would use exec and then run node.js script from CasperJS spawn.